# How to output all files in a folder to a file

Tags: powershell

I have a question about powershell.

How would i output all filenames from all the files in a folder (not the extension, only the filename of the files) to a texfile listing each name with a space on each line will be a list of names in the textfile?

```
Example, in the folder these files exist.
text1.txt text2.txt text3.txt

in the textfile i want to list them as this when they are put in there.
text1
text2
text3
```

Comment: As a 5year+ member you already should know [ASK] and please take the [tour] (again). SO isn't a free script writing service nor a forum, but a site for programmers helping colleagues who got stuck with a distinct problem. Own research and serious coding attempts are expected. [Edit] the question to include **your** code in a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
$path = "your path"

Get-ChildItem $path -recurse | ForEach-Object { $_.BaseName } | Out-File .\output.txt
```

Which first extracts all files recursively with [`GetChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6), then redirect with [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-6) the `BaseName` of each file to `output.txt`.

If you don't want to recurse all children inside the folder, remove `-recurse`.